# Apigee Quota type not defined

Tags: apigee

When the Quota type is not defined in a quota limit policy, (which means that is is a default Quota configuration), what happens when the limit is exceeded? For how long will the requests be throttled before the client can successfully send requests?

Apigee documentation only states the below. It does not provide any information on the behavior -
Default: A Quota policy that does not explicitly define a type is a default Quota configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In the default configuration, quota enforcement is `calendar` type without `StartTime` configured.

The `StartTime` will be calendar/clock start of the corresponding interval such as hour, day, week or month.  Example:

```
<Quota name="QuotaPolicy">
    <Allow count="10000"/>
    <Interval>1</Interval>
    <TimeUnit>hour</TimeUnit>
</Quota>
```

Let's say the current time when the first message received is `2013-07-08 07:35:28`.  Then, the `StartTime` will be `2013-07-08 07:00:00` and corresponding end time is `2013-07-08 08:00:00` (1 hour from the `StartTime`).

Comment: By the way, this has now been updated in the Apigee documentation.